# can't I have both keywords on the same line : private final...()?

Tags: java

I do know that when you make a method `final` in java, it cannot be overridden.

When a method is `private`, it can only be accessed by methods and members of that given class in which the method exists.

So, does it mean that since the method cannot be accessed it is no use trying to check if it can be overridden because I wrote the following declaration and I get the following warning :

> private method addCode is declared final

```
 private final void addCode(String code)
     {
        //codes here...
     }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, private means no-one is going to access the method apart from you and final means no-one can overload the method. But since the only person with access to it is you, it makes no sense. You cannot be your own superclass.

It is like locking a document for writes whent the only person with the access to the file is you.

Answer (score 2):

A private method cannot be overridden because it is not visible to child classes.

Comment: croakin, is that why i can't have both the private and final on the same declaration line?

Comment: It is a warning because it makes no sense to have a private final method. Note: a private final variable does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

A method cannot be overriden if it's final, private or static.

Comment: so, I was correct, it doesn't make sense making a method private as well as final or static at the same time? hmm...

Comment: to be precise, if the method is private or static, it is redondant to also flag it as final. The reverse isn't true though.